# JQuery Autofill with Keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I would like to put in "max" and "min" values in separate input fields and then have another set of input fields autofill with all the integers in between and included the min and max #'s. I've never used JS before so I'm not sure if there is a method for this or if you need to loop through the numbers?

```
$("#min1").keyup(function(){
    $("#speed1").val(this.value);
});


 $("#max1").keyup(function(){
    $("#speed5").val(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one event for the boths (use `input` instead of `keyup` it's more effecient when we want to track input field change) then call `result()` function that will clear result div then generate input fields :

```js
function result(min,max){
   $("#result").html("");
     
   for(var i=min;i<=max;i++)
       $("#result").append('<input type="number" value="'+i+'"/>');
}

$("body").on('input', '#min1,#max1', function(){
   var min = $('#min1').val();
   var max = $('#max1').val();
  
   if( min!="" && max!="")
     if( min<max )
       result(min, max);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="min1" type="number" placeholder="min" value="0"/>
<input id="max1" type="number" placeholder="max" value="0"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```